# create a park tag with css and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created 4 predefined sizes for circle tags.
I want create a park tag ( cloud tag ) where the tags are dispersant randomly just for first time. but I cannot make it working
here is my code :

**HTML**

```
<div id="tags-cloud">
    <div class="tag-1 tag">tag name</div>
    <div class="tag-2 tag">tag name</div>
    <div class="tag-3 tag">tag name</div>
    <div class="tag-4 tag">tag name</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
tags-cloud {
 background-color:white;
 padding:10px;
 margin-top:10px;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:600px;
}

.tag {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 text-align:center;
 text-transform:capitalize;
 border-radius:100%;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
}

.tag-1{width:46px;height:46px;background:#DC5E0A;line-height:46px;}
.tag-2{width:58px;height:58px;background:#05F9EB;line-height:58px;}
.tag-3{width:76px;height:76px;background:#4B05F9;line-height:76px;}
.tag-4{width:89px;height:89px;background:#9EDC0A;line-height:89px;}
```

> **JS CODE**

```
$('.tag').each(function() {
        var size = Math.round(Math.random()*550+20);
        $(this).css({
            'top':size/2,
            'bottom':size/2,
            'left':size/2,
            'right':size/2,
            zIndex:size
        })
    });
```

> **the result I want :**

[image]

> **My result**

[image]

> **JS FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/s1aoxf1o/

Comment: You're using the same value for your top/left coordinates. you need DIFFERENT top/left coordinates,

Comment: yes thanks, but even the  top/left have different coordinates, it's still not working well

Comment: well, yeah, you need different values all over. `top = 4, right = 4, left = 4, bottom = 4, size = 4` will give you exactly what your "bad" image is showing.

Answer (score 3):

As has already been pointed out, you need different top and left coordinates.  Otherwise, all circles will lie along a diagonal line.

You then need a way of determining if two circles are touching (or are within a given "margin" of each other).  You can do this by determining the center (origin) of the circles and applying the distance formula:

[image]

If the distance is greater than the sum of the radii plus the margin, then the circles are okay.

Here's the code for that:

```
function touching(margin) {
  var result= false;
  $('.tag').each(function() {
    var t1= $(this),
        t1radius= t1.width()/2,
        t1x= t1.offset().left + t1radius,
        t1y= t1.offset().top  + t1radius;

    $('.tag').not(t1).each(function() {
      var t2= $(this);
          t2radius= t2.width()/2,
          t2x= t2.offset().left + t2radius,
          t2y= t2.offset().top  + t2radius,
          dist= Math.sqrt((t2x-t1x)*(t2x-t1x) + (t2y-t1y)*(t2y-t1y));

      if(t1radius && t2radius && dist<t1radius+t2radius+margin) {
        result= true;
      }
    })
  });
  return result;
} //touching
```

In the following code, the circles are placed randomly within their container until they're not "touching" within 20px of each other.  Background colors are assigned randomly.  The font size is a function of the circle size:

```
$('.tag').each(function(idx) {
  do {
    var container= $(this).parent(),
        diam= Math.round(Math.random() * 75 + 50),
        top = Math.round(Math.random() * (container.height() - diam)),
        left= Math.round(Math.random() * (container.width()  - diam)),
        bg= '#'+(Math.random()*128+32<<0).toString(16)+(Math.random()*128+32<<0).toString(16)+(Math.random()*128+32<<0).toString(16);

    $(this)
      .css({
        top         : top,
        left        : left,
        width       : diam,
        font        : diam/5+'px verdana',
        lineHeight  : diam+'px',
        background  : bg
      })
      .html('tag '+(idx+1));
  } while(touching(20));
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/01ss0x50/6/)

Comment: Great, and helpful answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to add random variables for left and top.
On absolute positioned elements you only need left or right and top or bottom.

```
$(function() {
  $('.tag').each(function() {
    var size = Math.round(Math.random() * 550 + 20);
    var left = Math.round(Math.random() * 550 + 20);
    var top = Math.round(Math.random() * 550 + 20);
    $(this).css({
      'top': top / 2,
      'left': left / 2,
      zIndex: size
    })
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.tag').each(function() {
    var size = Math.round(Math.random() * 550 + 20);
    var left = Math.round(Math.random() * 550 + 20);
    var top = Math.round(Math.random() * 550 + 20);
    $(this).css({
      'top': top / 2,
      'left': left / 2,
      zIndex: size
    })
  });
})
```

```css
tags-cloud {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
.tag {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
.tag-1 {
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  background: #DC5E0A;
  line-height: 46px;
}
.tag-2 {
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  background: #05F9EB;
  line-height: 58px;
}
.tag-3 {
  width: 76px;
  height: 76px;
  background: #4B05F9;
  line-height: 76px;
}
.tag-4 {
  width: 89px;
  height: 89px;
  background: #9EDC0A;
  line-height: 89px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tags-cloud">
  <div class="tag-1 tag">tag name</div>
  <div class="tag-2 tag">tag name</div>
  <div class="tag-3 tag">tag name</div>
  <div class="tag-4 tag">tag name</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And can We add margin between circles ?

Comment: Yes you can, with javascript you need to store all the sizes, positions and margins of each circle. On every new creation you need to check if any of the numbers is in between (+ margin) of the existing numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that's working. for me I want tags dispersant randomly just for first time, not different figure on every reload. but my solution not realy random positions of tags but it make circles dispersant  in the area.

> **HTML CODE**

```
<div id="tags-cloud">
    <div class="tag-1 tag">tag name</div>
    <div class="tag-2 tag">tag name</div>
    <div class="tag-3 tag">tag name</div>
    <div class="tag-4 tag">tag name</div>
</div>
```

> **CSS CODE**

```
tags-cloud {
 background-color:white;
 padding:10px;
 margin-top:10px;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:600px;
}

.tag {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 text-align:center;
 text-transform:capitalize;
 border-radius:100%;
 display:inline-block;
}

.tag-1{width:46px;height:46px;background:#DC5E0A;line-height:46px;}
.tag-2{width:58px;height:58px;background:#05F9EB;line-height:58px;}
.tag-3{width:76px;height:76px;background:#4B05F9;line-height:76px;}
.tag-4{width:89px;height:89px;background:#9EDC0A;line-height:89px;}
```

To make it working I use Masonry

> **JS CODE**

```
var $container = $('#tags-cloud');
    $container.masonry({
      columnWidth: 50,
      itemSelector: '.tag'
    });
```

> **JS FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/anp6uro8/1/

Well, this is just a solution between many other solutions like @kay's solution and @Rick Hitchcock's solution.